# Mocking http calls with AuthHttp in AngularJS 2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking

In my Angular 2.0.0 app, I'm trying to mock an HTTP call in a service that uses `AuthHttp` rather than `Http`.

```
@Injectable()
export class FundingPlanService {
  constructor(private http: AuthHttp);

  getFundingPlans(): Observable<FundingPlan[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/fundingplans')
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      }).map((json: any) => {
        // some logic here
        return fundingPlans;
      });
  }
}
```

In the test, I've scrambled bits and pieces found here and there on the net, like so:

```
describe('Service: FundingPlan', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        FundingPlanService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: (http) => new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http),
            deps: [Http]
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([FundingPlanService, MockBackend], fakeAsync((service: FundingPlanService, backend: MockBackend) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      expect(false).toBe(true);
      expect(connection.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Get);
      expect(connection.request.url).toBe('http://localhost:8080/api/fundingplans');
    });

    let fundingPlans = service.getFundingPlans();
  })));
});
```

`Http` uses a `MockBackend`, and `AuthHttp` uses the `Http` with mocked backend:

```
LOG: '*** const ', AuthHttp{http: Http{_backend: MockBackend{connectionsArray: ...
```

But the `expect` statements are never executed. Just to be sure, I've added `expect(false).toBe(true);` yet the test finishes with `SUCCESS`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

### 1st problem:

You're missing the asynchronous behaviour of your request, there's multiple ways to implement async tests:

By wrapping the test in an `async` zone:

```
it('should ...', async(inject([FundingPlanService, MockBackend], (service: FundingPlanService, backend: MockBackend) => {
    ... 
    ...
    }));
```

By using `done()` callback parameter:

```
it('should ...', (done) => {inject([FundingPlanService, MockBackend], (service: FundingPlanService, backend: MockBackend) => {
      ...
      ...
      done();
    }});
```

You used `fakeAsync` but this is for fake async timers, here you are explicitly using an async call so you should use one of those two methods.

## 2nd problem:

You're subscribing to the connection backend which is never called because you never call `http`, subscribing to the connection backend should be used to specify which response you want to get in the mockup:

```
it('should ...', async(inject([FundingPlanService, MockBackend], (service: FundingPlanService, backend: MockBackend) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        const options: ResponseOptions = new ResponseOptions(
                {
                    body   : "Your body as string",
                    headers: new Headers(),
                    status : 200
                }
            );
            conn.mockRespond(new Response(options));
    });
    //And then your expectations
    expect(service.getFundingPlans()).toBe(dunnoWhat);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks you for the complementary info on the various `async`, `done` callback and `fakeAsync`. The latter can easily be confused for what it is not.

Comment: The first solution does not go through 'false==true'. The second solution yields `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`